# Eclipse unable to detect that a server has started

Tags: eclipse, detect

I've been trying to solve a mind puzzling problem. I'm currently unable to use any server with eclipse, as they all start correctly but eclipses seems to be unable to see it.
I've tried using sun-java6-jdk instead of openjdk6.
I've tried using the command line given by the debug view and everything went fine
I've successfully reproduced that bug with Glassfish 3.1, JBoss 5.1, Tomcat 6.0

I'm trying to figure out how this is possible. Maybe a network issue? 
Has anyone met the same problem ?

Comment: Are you starting the servers through eclipse? Or are you starting them externally and hoping eclipse will see them as well? Are the servers defined in eclipse configured to have the same settings as the app server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, but i'm not sure of what causes the problems. I've entered my computer local IP instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 and it now detects the server is running. 
My educated guess is that our IT proxy scripts do not exclude 127.0.0.1 from the proxified addresses.

Thanks for your time Mike !