# how to increase the startup time of server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

how to disable server start up time out in eclipse
    As it is giving error in starting server  "server can not start within given time" start-
 up time has expired.

Pls Help.

Thanks for answering.
           Actually i am using jboss 4.0 server which is taking too much time to start.
before the complete start has occur. eclipse show that error "server can not start within given time"
           i want to  disable this feature of eclipse.

Pls Help.

Comment: Here you have a similar question but Tomcat case:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11371393/833336

Comment: thanks, i have done it by myself.what it needs to increase the time-out of eclipse.by right clicking on server and selecting open tab.we should not to disable the server startup rather we have to increase the time out time.

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse open menu `Window -> Show View -> Other`, 
A new window `Show View` will be open then select `Server` under `Server` folder, then select it (or) Simply click on keyboard for open Show View [ `Alt + Shift + Q, Q` ] it is a eclipse short key. See Below Picture.

[image]

Here I used JBOSS v5.0.2.
A Servers window is opened then `right click on JBOSS v5.0.2` and click `Open` option, See below Picture.

[image: JBOSS Servers View]

An Overview window is opened after click on Open option then click on `Timeouts` leftside here `Start` time shows 50 secs by default then increase start time to `900` it is equal to 15 mins, then click on `Save` button for saving changes. Below Picture shows the detailed perspective.

[image: JBoss Overview]

**If you face again this problem then increase time in Timeouts tab.**

Answer (score 0):

Since I saw you're using JBOSS, here is a link with a description how to do it:
[link](http://techthinking.net/2010/02/how-to-increase-server-timeout-in-eclipse/)