# Can't start Tomcat through Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm running Tomcat 8 and eclipse mars on Ubuntu.  When I try to start Tomcat through eclipse, it just hangs.  I tried the solutions in [Tomcat Not Starting Through Eclipse (Timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371393/tomcat-not-starting-through-eclipse-timeout)
including:

1. setting my hosts file has 127.0.0.1 localhost
2. setting Window ->
       Preferences -> General -> Network Connections to Direct
3. adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to eclipse.ini

Console output:

```
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.28.0
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.13.0-24-generic
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/weblogic/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:43256
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/weblogic/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/weblogic/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/endorsed
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3816 ms
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 26, 2015 12:06:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2091 ms
```

Comment: `INFO: Server startup in 2091 ms` it started

Comment: What makes you say "it hangs" ? What happens when you try to go to http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: @Gimby, When I go to "http://localhost:8080/" I still get a 404.  Also, since I've always used Weblogic, I was expecting it to say something like "Running" but I guess that term isn't used in Tomcat.

Comment: A 404 is actually good as that is a response from the running server. Perhaps you are talking about the deployment of the application which is "hanging" and not the server itself?

Comment: @Gimby,  When I start Tomcat from the bin/startup.sh, both my application and the default Tomcat webpage come up.  When I start it from Eclipse, both return 404s.

Comment: All clues that hint that closer examination of the server runtime configuration in Eclipse needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I double clicked on the server, went down to "Server Location" and switched from "Use workspace metadata" to "Use Tomcat installation".

Answer (score 0):

It has started. What are you looking for?

Go to localhost:8080 from any web-browser. If you have defined the index.html file, then it will show the output there.

Comment: When going to localhost:8080, I get a 404 when starting it from Eclipse, but when I start it from the bin script file, I get the Tomcat webpage.

Comment: that's because there is no default index file define in the tomcat of eclipse. You can try it by this:
Create a dynamic web project 'test' while creating it check the check box to Generate web.xml and don't forget to define index.html then run that application by right click on that and select run as >> run on server now the link which will open in web browser contains the things you have in that index.html.