# IBM websphere 8.5 not starting

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I am unable to start IBM websphere 8.5. There is no error/exception thrown. It just shows:

> WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business and server status as
>   [Starting, Syncronized]

I checked in logs but no error was found. I even increased heap size as

```
Initial Heap Size: 1024
Maximum Heap Size: 1280
```

still the server doesn't start.

Comment: Tried searching for that error message?

Comment: I created new profile. Post creation server starts but as soon as i deploy my ear it doesn't start. No error in logs.. It loads all the configuration and freezes at  [Starting, Syncronized].

Comment: More information is helpful, but it should go into your question; never put that into comments. And: you did not answer my question: did you try to search for that error code?!

Comment: I am sorry i can't understand. Which error code you are talking about?

Comment: Like the stuff in the yellow box in your question?

Comment: yes i did, but no help.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with Eclipse. Can you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12745589/6216002)?

Comment: Just start server from the command line, thats issue between Eclipse and WebSphere communication. Server starts successfully if you see `open for e-business` message. You may try to change protocol in server configuration to SOAP.

Comment: Yes it seems to be problem between eclipse and websphere. I am able to debug application though its showing server status as [Starting, Synchronized]. Thanks all for help.