# Eclipse and Netbeans with Tomcat: it is started, but don't work

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, netbeans, wildfly

I have installed, under debian jessie, tomcat 9.0.7 , netbeans 8.2 and eclipse oxigen.

If i start tomcat from command line, it works, i see the welcome page in my browser.

If i start it from eclipse, in the console i see all info messages that finish with: "Server startup in 2526 ms", but the state in server tag, is "starting, syncronized". After a while, eclipse tells: "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 450 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor", but also if i increase the timeout, it doesn't work.

The same thing for netbeans.

I tried to install tomcat 8.5, no changes.

I tried to install wildfly 12.0, same thing.

No firewalls, no proxys, no strange network things.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat Not Starting Through Eclipse (Timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371393/tomcat-not-starting-through-eclipse-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It was a problem of firewall, that blocked some ports.